# What is the meaning of big hex number in jstack output showning "parking to wait for ..."?

Tags: java, locking, jstack

I have jstack where many thread are in state WAITING with description "parking to wait for " like:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.3/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000307db96c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.3/LockSupport.java:194)
```

What is this big hex number? Is it time? Is it identifier?

EDIT

I have dumped state of my Java application thereads with threads that work very long (few days) in the morning and in the afternoon. I see that  "waiting on condition" is with the same big hex number, but other big hex number in "parking to wait for" is different:

In the morning:

```
"qtp792232038-1037-..." #1037 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=787.64ms elapsed=528768.56s tid=0x00007f164004a800 nid=0x1346
waiting on condition  [0x00007f181fffd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.3/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000030a69c410> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.3/LockSupport.java:194)
    ...
```

After few hours:

```
"qtp792232038-1037-..." #1037 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=787.64ms elapsed=546900.36s tid=0x00007f164004a800 nid=0x1346
waiting on condition  [0x00007f181fffd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.3/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000307db96c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.3/LockSupport.java:194)
    ...
```

Comment: The Hex No. is value of the object in the Hexadecimal number format

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'd say it's the internal object ID which often is based on the initial memory adress (depends on the JVM).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an internal identifier for the lock object.

You can use this to see which thread is waiting for which other thread.

Search the thread dump for this id, there should be another thread mentioned with a stack frame that is holding the lock with the same id.

Comment: It my jstack from application using Jetty HTTP Server I see those big hex numbers from line `parking to wait for` only once. I'm not sure if thread is in blocking socket write.